# QGIS crashes when I try to open the extension tab

Tags: qgis, data, repository

As I try to boot up the manager in order to manage my currently installed plugins, QGIS tries to load some of my custom data/plugins repositories from work. Those need some specific credentials to access, they work on other computers.

As QGIS tries to load the first one, it freezes as it asks for my IDs. What I am looking for is a simple fix without needing to delete and install QGIS back again, maybe by somehow erasing the repositories without opening the extension tab or trying to load them for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable those repositories by going to the menubar:

```
Settings > Options > Advanced
```

Click the "I will be careful..." button and find the following path:

```
Qgis > plugin-repos
```

Expaned the ones you are interested in, select the `enabled` property and set the value from `true` to `false`:

[image: Options]

When you're finished, click <kbd>OK</kbd> and restart QGIS. Hopefully now, those repositories should be disabled and won't ask for thy credentials:

[image: Repositories]

Comment: @MoreauColin - Most welcome, glad it helped :)